# Finding all matches in a vector in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

*This question is a follow up to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393194/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-a-column-of-vectors-in-data-table-whe).*

I have a vector of id's, `sampleIDs`. 
I also have a data.table, `rec_data_table`, keyed by bid and containing a column, 
`A_IDs.list` where each elements is a collection (a vector) of aIDs.

I would like to create a second data.table containing `sampleIDs` and where 
 For each `aID`, there is a corresponding vector of all the bIDs for which 
that aID appears in the `A_IDs.list` column.

Example:

```
> rec_data_table
   bid counts names_list A_IDs.list
1: 301     21        C,E       3,NA
2: 302     21          E         NA
3: 303      5      H,E,G     8,NA,7
4: 304     10        H,D        8,4
5: 305      3          E         NA
6: 306      5          G          7
7: 307      6        B,C        2,3

> sampleIDs
[1] 3 4 8

AB.dt <- data.table(aID=sampleIDs, key="aID")

# unkown step
AB.dt[ , bIDs := ????  ]

# desired result:
> AB.dt
    aid     bIDs
1:    3  301,307
2:    4      304
3:    8  303,304
```

---

I tried several different lines inside the `AB.dt[]` call. 
  The closest I could get was

```
rec_data_table[sapply(A_IDs.list, function(lst) aID %in% lst), bID]
```

which will give me the desired result for a given `aID`, and I can lapply 
  over `sampleIDs` to create a list of vectors and build the desired result.

However, I suspect there must be a more "data.table appropriate" method to accomplish this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

```
#--------------------------------------------------#
#           SAMPLE DATA                            #

library(data.table)
set.seed(101)

  rows <- size <- 7
  varyingLengths <- c(sample(1:3, rows, TRUE))
  A <-  lapply(varyingLengths, function(n) sample(LETTERS[1:8], n))
  counts <- round(abs(rnorm(size)*12))   
rec_data_table <- data.table(bID=300+(1:size), counts=counts, names_list=A, key="bID")

A_ids.DT <- data.table(name=LETTERS[c(1:4,6:8,10:11)], id=c(1:4,6:8,10:11), key="name")
rec_data_table[, A_IDs.list := sapply(names_list, function(n) c(A_ids.DT[n, id]$id))]
sampleIDs <- c(3, 4, 8)
```

Comment: your sample data does not work since we don't have `rows` or `size` defined.

Comment: thanks @Justin for pointing that out.  I've gone ahead and fixed the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the join of `tmp` to `A_ids.DT` in my answer to the previous question, you can get your desired output by looking up `sampleIDs` in `tmp`:

```
# ... from previous answer
# tmp <- A_ids.DT[tmp]

AB.dt <- setkey(tmp, id)[J(sampleIDs)][, list(bIDs = list(bID)),
                                       by = list(aid = id)]

# setkey(tmp, orig.order)
# previous answer continues ...
```

Note that the capitalization of your `bID` column is different in these two questions, however.  This is assuming, of course, that you *are not* executing the second to last line in your sample data. This ought to be faster than `%in%`-based approaches when there are many records due to the wonders of `data.table`'s binary search.

Comment: Thanks again for the input on this and the previous question

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives  your desired output:

```
myfun <- function(ids) {
  any(ids %in% sampleIDs)
}

rec_data_table[sapply(A_IDs.list, myfun),]

#    bID counts names_list A_IDs.list
# 1: 301     21        C,E       3,NA
# 2: 303      5      H,E,G     8,NA,7
# 3: 304     10        H,D        8,4
# 4: 307      6        B,C        2,3

rec_data_table[sapply(A_IDs.list, myfun), list(bID, A_IDs.list)]

#   bID A_IDs.list
# 1: 301       3,NA
# 2: 303     8,NA,7
# 3: 304        8,4
# 4: 307        2,3
```

You can use `unlist` on the `A_IDs.list` column to get a long data.table:

```
unique(na.omit(rec_data_table[sapply(A_IDs.list, myfun), list(bID, unlist(A_IDs.list))]))

#    bID V2
# 1: 301  3
# 2: 304  8
# 3: 301  7
# 4: 303  8
# 5: 304  4
# 6: 307  2
```

I'd suggest working with "long" data rather than the nested list construct you had above since it often leads to much simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

```
bIDs <- lapply(sampleIDs, function(x){rec_data_table$bID[sapply(rec_data_table$A_IDs.list, function(y){x %in% y})]})
AB.dt <- data.table(aID=sampleIDs, bIDs=bIDs)
```

maybe there is faster way, but this one works. :)